# Angular JS form POST to Jersey resource gives always null

Tags: angularjs, jersey

I want to execute a POST request from AngularJS to a Jersey REST server. This is the server code.

```
@POST
    @Path("/start")
    public Response start(@FormParam("name") String name) {
        System.out.println(name);
return Response.status(200).entity("Finished starting").build();
}
```

and this is the AngularJS code

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
                    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/Server/config/start';

                    var request = $http({method: 'POST', url: url,
    params:{name: 'test'}});

                    request.success(
                        function() {
                            //alert('it succeeded');
                        }
                    );

                    request.error(
                        function() {
                           // alert('it didnt work');
                        }
                    );

                };
```

I receive the request on the server but the parameter `name` is always `null`. Is it possible to solve the problem without changing the way of receiving the parameter on the server side (the `@FormParam`)? When I try the REST resource with a REST client `RESTClient` in firefox everything works fine.

As I said the server receive the request  and execute it, however I get an error on the AnularJS side, I don't know if it's related to the null problem, I think no because even if I change the a no-existing resource I get the same warning.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I solved the CORS issue but the received parameter is still null.

Comment: response is CORS?

Comment: No, it's a javax.ws.rs.core.Response . Even if I put a non-existing REST resource I get the same warning.

Comment: search by CORS, is full reponses in this site

Comment: `@FormParam` binds data from a `application-x-www-form-urlencoded` request body whereas Angular submits `application/json` by default

Comment: Your CORS issue is a separate issue from the server receiving null. To solve the null issue, follow the POST example at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike

Comment: and for the  CORS issue ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Comment: I solved the CORS issue but the parameter still null